# I'm having problems executing the expect command in bash on OSX

Tags: android, macos, bash, shell, expect

I need some assistance please.

**OS**: Mac oSX 10.9.4

**I'm running a bash script as follows:**
    sh create-emulator.sh AVD_16 14 /usr/local/ks-test-automation/avd-lib/ x86 QVGA

**The code:**

```
create_emulator() {
    android create avd -n $Emulator -t $Target -p $Location --abi $Processor --skin $Skin --force
    expect "Android 4.4.2 is a basic Android platform." 
    expect "Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]" 
    send "no\n"
}

main_method() {
    create_emulator
}

Emulator="$1"
Target="$2"
Location="$3"
Processor="$4"
Skin="$5"
main_method
```

**The output after exiting the scripts using ctrl+c:**

```
Couldn't read file "Android 4.4.2 is a basic Android platform.": no such file or directory
couldn't read file "Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]": no such file or directory
/usr/local/ks-test-automation/shell-script-lib/create-emulator.sh: line 14: send: command not found
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure your expect syntax is wrong.  Check [`expect` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expect.1.html)

Comment: I don't think `expect` does what you think it does.

Comment: @njzk2 I think `expect`s purpose is exactly what the OP is after, but he's not using it correctly.

Comment: I think you at least need to use `spawn` to start the `android` command. Also, you're missing the "shebang" as the first line of your script: `#!/usr/bin/expect` (if that's where expect is installed). I think your script is really be interpreted as a normal shell script and not with expect, given the error messages you're seeing.

Comment: ^^ @zerodiff: No, you can run the script under bash. You can run `expect -c` for that.

Comment: @anishsane I realize this, but I don't think this user is running it that way.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize that `expect` syntax is so close to `bash` function syntax... :(

Comment: @anishsane, it's not at all. See the discussion we're having in Aleks's answer

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is definitely wrong for what I understand you're trying to do.  Having scanned the [`expect` manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expect.1.html), I think the correct syntax is something like this:

```
create_emulator {
    expect <<END
        spawn android create avd -n $Emulator -t $Target -p $Location --abi $Processor --skin $Skin --force
        expect "Android 4.4.2 is a basic Android platform." 
        expect "Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile \[no\]" 
        send "no\r"
        expect eof
END
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However I'm now getting: spawn: command not found couldn't read file "Android 4.4.2 is a basic Android platform.": no such file or directory couldn't read file "Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]": no such file or directory /usr/local/ks-test-automation/shell-script-lib/create-emulator.sh: line 15: send: command not found /usr/local/ks-test-automation/shell-script-lib/create-emulator.sh: create-emulator.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token }' /usr/local/ks-test-automation/shell-script-lib/create-emulator.sh: create-emulator.sh: line 16: }'

Comment: @user3064523, I updated the quoting of the expect script. See if that helps you out.

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks for this. However I get the following error message: expect: option requires an argument -- c
usage: expect [-div] [-c cmds] [[-f] cmdfile] [args]

Comment: remove "-c" and try again. let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: @glennjackman. Works much better however I get this error now: spawn android create avd -n AVD_16 -t 14 -p /usr/local/ks-test-automation/avd-lib/ --abi x86 --skin QVGA --force
Android 4.4.2 is a basic Android platform.
invalid command name "no"
    while executing
"no"
    invoked from within
"expect "Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]" "

Comment: @glennjackman, I want to type the word "no" and then simulate pressing the enter key.

Comment: @glennjackman, I changed some of the code. I added a "\" before [no] in the second expect clause, which looks like this now: expect "Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile \[no]". Now I'm getting the following output: spawn android create avd -n AVD_16 -t 14 -p /usr/local/ks-test-automation/avd-lib/ --abi x86 --skin QVGA --force
Android 4.4.2 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]
o
Error: o is not a valid reply

Comment: @yodaqua I think the `expect` can take a regular expression and therefore treats the brackets as control sequence in a regex.  Put a backslash before `[` and also before `[`. I updated the answer with this change.

Comment: @AleksG, good catch. Tcl's brackets act like shell backticks: invoke a command and return the result. And like shell, command substitution is performed inside double quoted strings. In this case, there's no "no" command

Comment: @AleksG, thanks. I did do that earlier. I now get the following output: spawn android create avd -n AVD_16 -t 14 -p /usr/local/ks-test-automation/avd-lib/ --abi x86 --skin QVGA --force
Android 4.4.2 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]no

Comment: @AleksG, I think that the Send "no\r" isn't simulating pressing {ENTER}

Comment: @AleksG, working now! Changed Send "no\r" to Send "no\n"

Comment: Working code: create_emulator() {
    expect <<END
        spawn android create avd -n $Emulator -t $Target -p $Location --abi $Processor --skin $Skin --force
        expect "Android 4.4.2 is a basic Android platform." 
        expect "Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile \[no]" 
        send "no\n"
        expect eof
END
}